# Generic CSS templates anywhere (not layout)?

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a place where I can download a bunch of CSS stylesheets to change the appearance of my titles, links, paragraphs, etc. I am not an artist, so I am hoping to leverage other people's skills in choosing the right fonts, colors, sizes, etc.

I do not want to include layout because then it won't be as generic. Does anyone know where I can get something like this?

Comment: why don't you just leave browser to decide?

Comment: you don't have much of an eye for design do you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use only the text stylesheets of css frameworks like [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) ([typography example](http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/elements.html)) or [yui fonts](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/fonts/) etc. If you're looking for more designer-y css inspiration, you could <del>swipe</del> borrow css from a site such as [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/).